# How to reduce image size significantly before upload in in Ionic4 (Cordova)?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

Nowadays, the size of images captured by the mobile phone is too large that we can't simply upload those images to the server. For example, in my phone Redmi Note 7 Pro, I get images of size around `15MB` to `20MB`.

I am building a mobile application using `Ionic4`. In my app, I am asking the user to upload a profile picture. To upload a profile picture user can select the picture from the gallery & then he is prompted to crop window. After crop, we get the DataUri. From there, We upload the picture to the server.

On the server, I have added validation to validate image size should not be greater than `500KB`. Now, most of the time while uploading the images from the gallery, I see this image size validation error. It means, even after cropping the image, the size is not reducing to `500KB`. The code which I am using is given below.

I am pretty sure, this is the very basic need for every mobile application that deals with images. Could anyone provide me the proper way of reducing image size significantly before upload? This way, I will be storing lightweight images on server & payload size will also be small during upload.

**edit-profile-component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { UserModel } from 'app/modules/core/models/user-model';
import { ProfilePictureUrlModel } from 'app/modules/core/models/input-models/profile-picture-url-model';
import { AccountService } from 'app/modules/core/services/account.service';
import { ActionSheetController, LoadingController, ToastController, NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ImagePicker } from '@ionic-native/image-picker/ngx';
import { Crop } from '@ionic-native/crop/ngx';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/Camera/ngx';
import { AppConstants } from 'app/config/app.constants';
import { ImageUploadService } from 'app/modules/core/services/image-upload.service';
import { AppError } from 'app/modules/core/models/app-error';
import { AlertService } from 'app/modules/core/services/alert.service';
import { LoadingService } from 'app/modules/core/services/loading.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { ImageType } from 'app/modules/core/models/enums';
import { DataTransferService } from 'app/modules/core/services/data.transfer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-profile',
  templateUrl: './edit-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-profile.component.scss'],
})
export class EditProfileComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  loggedInUser: UserModel;
  subscription1: Subscription;
  subscription2: Subscription;

  constructor(private accountService: AccountService, private actionSheetController: ActionSheetController,
              private imagePicker: ImagePicker,  private crop: Crop,
              private imageUploadService: ImageUploadService,  private alertService: AlertService,
              private loadingService: LoadingService,  private toastController: ToastController,
              private navController: NavController, private dataTransferService: DataTransferService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedInUser = this.accountService.getLoggedInUser();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.subscription1) {
      this.subscription1.unsubscribe();
    }
    if (this.subscription2) {
      this.subscription2.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  openMyListing() {
    this.navController.navigateForward(AppConstants.Routes.MyListings);
  }

  async showChangeProfilePictureOptions() {
    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
      header: 'Profile photo',
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Gallery',
        icon: 'photos',
        handler: () => {
          this.imagePicker.getPictures({ maximumImagesCount: 1, outputType: 0 }).then((results) => {
            if (results.length > 0) {
             this.crop.crop(results[0], { quality: 100, targetHeight: 400, targetWidth: 400  }).then(newImage => {
                // 1. Show loading circle
                this.loadingService.showLoading('Updating profile picture..');

                // 2. update profile picture
                this.subscription1 =  this.imageUploadService.uploadProfilePicture(newImage, this.loggedInUser.id).subscribe((response) => {
                  if (response.success) {
                    this.subscription2 = this.accountService.uploadUserProfilePicture({
                        imageType: ImageType.UserProfilePicture,
                        filePathToSave: response.data.filePathToSave
                      } as ProfilePictureUrlModel).subscribe(childResponse => {
                        if (childResponse.success) {

                          // 1. Update profile picture on current page
                          this.loggedInUser.profilePicture = response.data.httpFilePath;

                          // 2. update profile picture in local storage
                          this.accountService.updateProfilePictureInLocalStorage(response.data.httpFilePath);

                          // 3. update profile picture in side menu
                          this.dataTransferService.updateUpdatedUserProfilePicture(response.data.httpFilePath);

                          // 4. show success notification
                          this.toastController.create({
                            position: 'bottom',
                            message: 'Profile picture updated successfully.',
                            duration: 2000
                          }).then((item) => {
                            item.present();
                          });

                        } else {
                          this.alertService.showHandledError(response);
                        }
                      }, (error: any) => { throw error; });
                    } else {
                      this.alertService.showHandledError(response);
                    }
                }, (error: any) => { throw error; });

                // 3. hide loading
                this.subscription1.add(() => {
                  if (this.subscription2) {
                    this.subscription2.add(() => {
                      this.loadingService.hideLoading();
                    });
                  } else {
                    this.loadingService.hideLoading();
                  }
                });
             }).catch(error => { throw error; });
            }
          }).catch(error => { throw error; });
        }
      }]
    });
    await actionSheet.present();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass those to option quality means image quality

```
 { quality: 50, targetHeight: 400, targetWidth: 400  }
```

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera
>
> ```
> const options: CameraOptions = {
>   quality: 100,<--- image quality
>   destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
>   encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
>   mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
> }
>
>     this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
>      // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
>      // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
>      let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
>     }, (err) => {
>      // Handle error
>     });
> ```

Comment: If we make quality to 50. Does it mean size will be reduced to half or it may reduce more than half of the actual size?

Comment: it reduce the half

Comment: image qulity 50%

Comment: size also reduce